# Applying lambda to a dataframe: works with > operator, but error with ==?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to replace groups from a group object that have more than one unique value in a particular column.
This line works, and replaces groups with >1 unique values in the column:

```
df.groupby(['ID'])\
  .apply(lambda group: group if len(set(group['col_name'])) > 1 else np.NaN)
```

However, if I just change the operator in the lambda to `==` (or `<=`), it fails:

```
df.groupby(['ID'])\
  .apply(lambda group: group if len(set(group['col_name'])) == 1 else np.NaN)
```

resulting in:
`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '_get_axis'`

I am having trouble connecting this error to my implementation, I tried casting 1 as a float to no avail.

If there is a better way to accomplish this same task, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: The issue is not the `==`, but the fact that the condition is now false, and used to be true (or vice versa). I suspect that the problem is the `np.NaN`.

Comment: @jungyh0218: In what universe does `len(set(...))` return a float?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for same `Series` like original column, so possible comparing and replace values by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col_name':list('abcdef'),
         'ID':list('aaabbc')
})

df['col_name'] =  df['col_name'].where(df.groupby('ID')['col_name'].transform('nunique') > 1)
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df.groupby('ID')['col_name'].transform('nunique') > 1
df['col_name'] =  np.where(m, df['col_name'], np.nan)

print (df)
  col_name ID
0        a  a
1        b  a
2        c  a
3        d  b
4        e  b
5      NaN  c
```